# Facebook Android SDK symbol

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to set up the Facebook SDK with Android Studio. The steps I followed-

- I downloaded, unzipped, and imported the facebook module into android studios.
- Within my project I imported `com.facebook.Session` in my main and added the `mavenCentral` repository as `repositories { mavenCentral() }` in my build.gradle above my dependencies as well as added
- compile `'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1'` to my dependencies.

Within my main file I have an alert in my "com.facebook.Session" line that is saying:

> "cannot resolve symbol 'facebook'".

I'm not sure why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

With Gradle, you don't need to do the first bullet, get rid of the Facebook module, you may have duplicate symbols, and that may be why it's not resolving.

All you need is the 2nd and 3rd bullet points. Then make sure Android Studio syncs the project. Then, you should be able to build.

Comment: I did what you said and got a successful build but "facebook" is still highlighted red in my main and when I mouse over it it declares "can not resolve symbol"

Comment: Can you create a public github repo with your project so I can take a look?